# Pandas: Alternative methods to using nested for-loops for cell-comparisons

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a problem with trying to find train-meeting at stations, but I'm having a hard time finding a way to do the necessary comparisons without using nested for-loops (which is way to slow, I have hundreds of thousands of data points).

My DataFrame-rows contains the following useful data: An arrival time (datetime), an departure time(datetime), a unique train-ID(string), the station that the train is located at between start and finish time (string) and a cell for train-ID's of trains it meet(string, empty at start). I want to find all pairs of rows that meet, meaning that I want that fulfil:

1. The time-interval from Row 1's arrival to departure overlaps with Row 2's arrival to departure time-interval.
2. Are located at the same station.

Additionally, there are no meetings with more than two trains involved.

I tried the following (code below): I created Interval-objects out of my arrival and departure time. Then I used nested for loops to compare each rows interval with every other row, and if they overlapped I checked if the station matched. If they did I stored each train-ID in the other's train-meeting-cell.

```
df_dsp['interval']  = [func(x,y) for x, y in zip(df_dsp['arrival'], df_dsp['departure'])]

meetings = np.empty([])
for i in range (1,len(df.index)):
    for q in range (1,len(df.index)):
        if (i < q): # Train meetings are symmetric.
            if df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('interval')].overlaps(df.iloc[q, df.columns.get_loc('interval')]):
                if df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('station')] == df.iloc[q, df.columns.get_loc('station')]:
                    df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('train_id_meeting')] = df.iloc[q, df.columns.get_loc('train_id')]
                    df.iloc[q, df.columns.get_loc('train_id_meeting')] = df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('train_id')]
```

I've taken a look at similar questions but have a hard time applying them to my dataset efficiently. My question is: How can I perform these comparisons faster?

**Edit**:
I can't give out the database (somewhat classified) but I made a representative dataset.

```py
d = {'arrival': [pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 1)), pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 3)),
                 pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 6)), pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 4))],
     'departure': [pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 3)), pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 5)), 
                   pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 7)), pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 6))],
     'station': ["a", "b", "a", "b"],
     'train_id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
     'meetings': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

In this sample-data, Row 2 and 4 would represent trains that meet at station "b". If this can be done faster without use of the Interval-object, I'd be happy to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the DataFrame.

```
d = {'arrival': [pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 1)), pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 3)),
                     pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 6)), pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 4))],
         'departure': [pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 3)), pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 5)), 
                       pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 7)), pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 6))],
         'station': ["a", "b", "a", "b"],
         'train_id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
         'meetings': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


Out: 

    arrival     departure   station     train_id    meetings
0   2012-05-01 01:00:00     2012-05-01 03:00:00     a   1   NaN
1   2012-05-01 03:00:00     2012-05-01 05:00:00     b   2   NaN
2   2012-05-01 06:00:00     2012-05-01 07:00:00     a   3   NaN
3   2012-05-01 04:00:00     2012-05-01 06:00:00     b   4   NaN
```

Convert datatimes to timestamps

```
df["arrival"] = df["arrival"].apply(lambda x: x.timestamp())
df["departure"] = df["departure"].apply(lambda x: x.timestamp())
```

Initiliaze two tables for merging.

```
df
df2 = df
```

Merge together both tables based on "Station", so they are already compared.

```
merge = pd.merge(df, df2, on=['station'])
table = merge[merge["train_id_x"] != merge["train_id_y"]]

arrival_x   departure_x     station     train_id_x  meetings_x  arrival_y   departure_y     train_id_y  meetings_y
1   1.335834e+09    1.335841e+09    a   1   NaN     1.335852e+09    1.335856e+09    3   NaN
2   1.335852e+09    1.335856e+09    a   3   NaN     1.335834e+09    1.335841e+09    1   NaN
5   1.335841e+09    1.335848e+09    b   2   NaN     1.335845e+09    1.335852e+09    4   NaN
6   1.335845e+09    1.335852e+09    b   4   NaN     1.335841e+09    1.335848e+09    2   NaN
```

Now use comparison vectorised algorithm

```
table[((table["arrival_x"] > table["arrival_y"]) & (table["arrival_x"] < table["departure_y"]) | (table["arrival_y"] > table["arrival_x"]) & (table["arrival_y"] < table["departure_x"]))]
```

Result:

```
arrival_x   departure_x     station     train_id_x  meetings_x  arrival_y   departure_y     train_id_y  meetings_y
5   1.335841e+09    1.335848e+09    b   2   NaN     1.335845e+09    1.335852e+09    4   NaN
6   1.335845e+09    1.335852e+09    b   4   NaN     1.335841e+09    1.335848e+09    2   NaN
```

Disclaimer: This algorithm can be even more improved. But I hope you get the idea. Instead doing for loops, use Pandas and Numpy functions which are faster.

Comment: This is amazing! I didn't know that I could write the vectorized comparison this way in tandem with Merge, so this really opened up doors for further inquiry while also solving my problem. This is a breakthrough in my project, all thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

My head is going to explode. Sorry I can't comment given I haven't enough points. Is there anyway we can have your database to test on it?

Does have to match on Row 1 with Row 2 (pairs) or Row 1 with Row any?

You are actually doing O(n^2), it could be improved for sure, but it has to be very well understood what the problem is.

The most efficient algorithm in Pandas is trying to understand everything as a Matrix which can be compared and worked on with Numpy Arrays (Vectorisation) but I think this is not the case.

What is the data type of "interval"?

Comment: Made an edit to the question, hopefully that answers some questions. The matching is done with any pair of rows, not just adjacent rows.

Comment: Done :) Hope it helps you